# INSERTing UTF-8 string into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, insert

I am struggling to INSERT a UTF-8 encoded string into MySQL table from a PHP script:

The table is set to collation "utf8_unicode_ci", the field is a **text** field, also collation "utf8_unicode_ci". The string is being read in from another site, and looks like this:

```
$str = "Bonka bдver, е hцra va man bara ta't en fika.";
```

...everything looks good right before the INSERT. If I *echo($str);* I see the unicode characters:

```
Bonka bдver, е hцra va man bara ta't en fika.
```

...but when I try to INSERT this string into the MySQL table, like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (id, mystring)
        VALUES ('','".addslashes($str)."');";
if ( !mysqli_query( $mysqli, $sql ) ) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error( $mysqli ) );
    die();
}
```

...what gets written to the database is:

```
Bonka bÐ´ver, Ðµ hÑ†ra va man bara ta't en fika.
```

I'm pretty sure the table is alright, (because I tried inserting the same string via PhpMyAdmin and it worked fine), and I'm pretty sure the source string is alright, (because I can output it via echo() and it's in unicode), so I guess the problem must be the way that I am inserting it? What am I doing wrong?

PS. I tried it without the addslashes() on the $str, but then I just get the error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 't en fika.
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Maybe this link will help you. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811257/problems-in-inserting-utf-8-string-into-database-and-then-outputting-it-to-web-p?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @Newbi3 - found the answer now thanks to Niet, but this link also provides the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the charset on the connection to UTF-8 with [mysqli_set_charset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php).

Comment: Brilliant, works! Thanks, I spent the last 4 hours on this... ;-)
So I guess setting the collation to unicode wasn't enough!

Comment: 's one of the main reasons I work purely in single-byte character sets. There's just too much work involved in making things work in UTF-8!